# Java class can't read the jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

i'm using eclipse noen and i've created a jar file contains only one java file. but when I added to the application library   it still can't be seen.

Comment: Your jar file should contain compiled classes (not uncompiled java source files).

Comment: Can elaborate the problem?

Comment: for sure i've created the jar file using the generated .class file. but I still have the same error

Comment: for people who gave me - .. maybe you are experts but I need help your -'s didnt help me..

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't be seen"? What is the fully qualified class name? How did you create the jar?

Comment: when I call the class name (the name of the class inside the jar) an error appears "ClassName cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the strutcture or an example of the contents of the JAR file?
JAR files should contain compiled java classes, not ".java" files.
If you are using Eclipse, create the JAR file by exporting the project.

Reference: https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm

Comment: I have one java file and I want to use it as a jar file. I compiled it using javac in cmd. and created the jar file from the generated .class file by this command jar -cvf className.jar *.*

Comment: Create the JAR file using Eclipse. I have posted the documentation explaining how to do that in my answer

Comment: thnx for the link.. I used this way but still have the same problem

Comment: @BDeveloper, can you please clarify and check the class fully qualified name, I mean, the package + class name. In the jar it should be structured in folder (packages)

Comment: I put the .java in a package called "Main". but when I open the generated manifest in JAR nothing is written except Manifest-version: 1.0.

Comment: I created a project of the .java file that I need to export to JAR under package Main.

Comment: Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces. [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)